# Windows Phone 7 - Incoming Call Screen

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

Is there anyway when receiving a call to add data to the incoming call screen?
I'd like to be able to add text to that screen if possible.

Update:

If there is no way to currently add text to this screen is there a way to trigger code based off of an incoming phone call?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only way you can do anything in relation to an incoming call is be informed that this has happened via the Obscured event.
Be aware that other things (such as an alarm) also trigger this event and there is no way within your app to know what caused your app to be obscured.

Comment: So it looks like for the first time I have been absolutely blocked from doing something because of the limitations of this phone.  Kind of a bummer actually.  But thank you for the information.  The Obscured event is what fires but they offer no information from it.