# WP7 how to capture incoming call information

Tags: windows-phone-7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Windows Phone 7 - Incoming Call Screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10608122/windows-phone-7-incoming-call-screen)

Windows Phone 7 how to get the incoming call information？i‘ve searched a long time，but I can't found the solution.
Is there anyone konw hot to get the incoming call info in Windows Phone 7?
Thank you very much!

Comment: I don't think you can: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10608122/windows-phone-7-incoming-call-screen

Comment: @AdrianFaciu i think i‘ve saw it，3Q

Comment: @Nick please tell in which app you've seen that, because I'm pretty sure it isn't possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no public APIs which allow you to know if a call has taken place let alone get details of the call.

Some operators provide access to account related information (including call history) but this is accessed via remote services and not via any APIs on the phone.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it.
Here is a [list of accessible API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff402531%28v=vs.92%29.aspx#appplat_overview_runtime)

- **Silverlight**
- **XNA Framework**
- **Sensors**
- **Media**
- **Data** - Isolated storage allows an application to create and maintain data in a sandboxed isolated virtual folder. All I/O operations are restricted to isolated storage and do not have direct access to the underlying operating system file system. This prevents unauthorized access and data corruption by other applications.
  Structured data can be stored in a relational database and can be accessed by using LINQ to SQL.
- **Location**

So, no SMS, no call history ect.